# How to use custom model function in eloquent

Tags: laravel

I want to get all user's online friends, how can I call a custom model function inside the eloquent condition?
this is my code

```
$friends = $user->friends()->where(function (Builder $query){
        $query->where('friend', 'yes');
    })
   ->get();
```

and this is my function in model

```
 public function getIsOnlineAttribute(): bool
{
    // check if the user is online or not 
    return $this->is_online;
}
```

I can access is_online after eloquent by foreach, but in my case, I want to check everything in one step ( inside where condition in eloquent). how can I do that???

Comment: Where is your `static model function`?

Comment: sorry I mean custom function getIsOnlineAttribute()

Comment: I don't think Laravel would allow that. As you can see from the [document](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor), custom attributes only exist after the model instance is fully retrieved.

Comment: You already seem to have an attribute `is_online` which you return in your method, what's the use of creating a `getIsOnlineAttribute()` method then?

Comment: @brombeer how can I use the attribute in eloquent condition?? because I want to check if the user is a friend and is_online in the same request

Comment: Have you tried it with a `scope`? See docs (feel free to search for a tutorial): https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#query-scopes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me :)

```
$friends = $user->friends()
    ->simplePaginate()
    ->reject(function ($friend) {            
        return $friend->is_online === false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use conditions for eloquent accessors, in this case you can use (assume `1` is database column value):

```
$friends = $user->friends()->where('is_online', 1)->get();
```

or

```
$friends = $user->friends()->whereIsOnline(1)->get();
```

or you can create eloquent scope on your model:

```
public function scopeIsOnline($query) {
    $query->where('is_online',1);
}
```

and you can use this eloquent scope on your controller in this way:

```
$friends = $user->friends()->isOnline()->get();
```

Comment: 'is_online' is not a column in the database :(.  it is a custom attribute. it exists after the model is retrieved.

Comment: which is database column?

Comment: there is a user id in another table (session)  and there is this function in the model                                          public function getIsOnlineAttribute(): bool
    {
        return $this->exists && Session::isOnline($this->getKey());
    }

Comment: After get results from query builder you can filter collection, in this way you can use is_online property from eloquent accessor

Comment: is this the best practice even if there are thousands in the collection ??

Comment: it is not best practice but i don't understand what you really want to do

Comment: "You can't use conditions for eloquent accessors" says who?